# не работает импорт из соседнего приложения Django

Tags: python, django

У меня есть два приложения: **blog** и **main1213**. Я хочу получить значение **page** из **views.py** в приложении **main1213** и передать его в **blog**, но получаю ошибку, что такого модуля нет.

*blog/tests.py*

```
from django.test import TestCase
from django.urls import resolve
from main1213.views import page


class HomePageTest(TestCase):
    def test_home_page_returns_correct_html(self):
        found = resolve('/')
        self.assertEqual(found.func, page)
```

*main1213/views.py*

```
page = None
```

выдает

> from main1213.views import page
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'main1213'

Оба приложения добавлены в **INSTALLED_APPS**, в **apps.py** имена прописаны, сервер запускал, запускал через **PyCharm**, пометил директории как **Sources root**.
Помогите, что делать?